# On what basis can I decide between using a clob vs blob?

Tags: sql, blob, clob

I have objects of Java class that I want to store in database. The entire object can be represented as String, and hence it can be maintained in the database as a clob. But I am not sure if I have to maintain it as clob or blob. What should be the basis on which I have to decide between clob and blob in situations like these?

Comment: Take a look at the similar question [Explanation of a BLOB and a CLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563235/explanation-of-a-blob-and-a-clob)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the similar questions that have been asked

- [Help me understand the difference between CLOBs and BLOBs in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018073/help-me-understand-the-difference-between-clobs-and-blobs-in-oracle)
- [I'm looking for a good explanation of a BLOB and a CLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563235/im-looking-for-a-good-explanation-of-a-blob-and-a-clob)

Comment: Thank you for those links, I did look at them before submitting my question. They try to answer the difference between clob and blob. I felt some one could offer a better explanation for my question, since I could use either of those to store my objects in my case.