# DT_TEXT concatenating rows on Flat File Import

Tags: ssis

I have a project that imports a TSV file with a field set as text stream (DT_TEXT).

When I have invalid rows that get redirected, the DT_TEXT fields from my invalid rows gets appended to the first proceeding valid row.

Here's my test data:

Tab-delimited input file: ("tsv IN")

```
CatID   Descrip
y   "desc1"
z   "desc2"
3   "desc3"
```

CatID is set as in integer (DT_I8)

Descrip is set as text steam (DT_TEXT)

Here's my basic Data Flow Task:

[image]
(I apologize, I cant post images until my rep is above 10 :-/ )

So my 2 invalid rows get redirected, and my 3rd row directs to sucess, 
But here is my "Success" output:

```
"CatID","Descrip"
"3","desc1desc2desc3"
```

Is this a bug when using DT_TEXT fields?  I am fairly new to SSIS, so maybe I misunderstand the use of text streams.  I chose to use DT_TEXT as I was having truncation issues with DT_STR.

If its helpful, my tsv Fail output is below:

```
Flat File Source Error Output Column,ErrorCode,ErrorColumn
x   "desc1"
,-1071607676,10
y   "desc2"
,-1071607676,10
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors did you get with dt_str?  What does your actual data look like? What is the longest string in your Descrip column?  Is it longer than 50 characters?

Answer (score 0):

You should really try and avoid using the **DT_TEXT, DT_NTEXT or DT_IMAGE** data types within SSIS fields as they can severely impact dataflow performance. The problem is that these types come through not as a CLOB (Character Large OBject), but as a BLOB (Binary Large OBject).

For reference see:

- CLOB: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_large_object
- BLOB: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLOB
- Difference: [Help me understand the difference between CLOBs and BLOBs in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018073/help-me-understand-the-difference-between-clobs-and-blobs-in-oracle)

Using **DT_TEXT** you cannot just pull out the characters as you would from a large array. This type is represented as an array of bytes and can store any type of data, which in your case is not needed and is creating problems concatenating your fields. (I recreated the problem in my environment)

My suggestion would be to stick to the **DT_STR** for your description, giving it a large OutputColumnWidth. Make it large enough so no truncation will occur when reading from your source file and test it out.