# How can I convert a hex-encoded JPEG stored in an Oracle CLOB column back to JPEG?

Tags: oracle, plsql, jpeg, blob, clob

I am migrating images from an Informix database to an Oracle database. The only output I received from the source was a single file which I have loaded into my Oracle database. The hex representation of an image looks like this: http://pastebin.com/vVBZ7qFG

If I take that same hex and convert it using http://i-tools.org/bin2hex I can output the JPEG image and this is the behaviour I am trying to mimic.

I need to loop through every record in my new table and output the image as a JPEG file in my filesystem, to be used elsewhere.

Can someone please help in replicating this behaviour using PLSQL on an Oracle 11gR2 database?

Should the hex be stored in a CLOB or BLOB column?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Storing images in databases is sloooooooooooow.

Comment: Why are you interested in a hex representation to start with? It's just binary data. Store it as a blob, without ever converting it to or from hex.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have not idea on how to dump an informix db but isn't the problem that a dump usually makes a (hex) character representation out of binary data as this automatically escapes special characters?

Comment: @JuergenHollfelder: Perhaps, if you just use tools out of the box. But I'm sure it should be possible to fetch the *programmatically* as just binary data.

Comment: @Jon skeet - That never crossed my mind... Will post back later with results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the whole reason you are dealing with hex is because you get a database dump from informix which is a flat file. So you either convert it back into binary and store it into a blob when you insert into the table or you first store it in a clob column and then write a pl/sql function that converts the clob to a blob and store the functions result into a blob column and then you drop the clob column.

So to the question "should the hex be stored in clob or blob?" If you need to store the hex then store ad interim then store it in clob column. The following link makes the difference between clob and blob clearer. The mentioned encoding difficulties should in my opinion not concern you.

[Help me understand the difference between CLOBs and BLOBs in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018073/help-me-understand-the-difference-between-clobs-and-blobs-in-oracle)

As in regards to the conversion itself converting from 2 characters in hex into decimal is not so difficult (I think) but I even found this hex2dec routine when googling it http://psoug.org/snippet/Convert-Hex-to-Decimal-Decimal-to-Hex_78.htm

The more difficult part would be to actually to step through the clob. Not exactly the same but gives you some idea is this link [Reading clob line by line with pl\sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647041/reading-clob-line-by-line-with-pl-sql)

Hope it helps.